# Handle 'drop' event with Apps script for Google Doc AddOn

Tags: html, google-apps-script, drag-and-drop, google-docs-api, droppable

I want to handle `ondrop` event for Google Docs with Apps Script AddOn.

I can see that Google Docs provide drag and drop functionality by which we can easily drag images from images.google.com to google doc. I want to handle this drop event by AddOn that I am developing.

Tried finding some inbuilt way to handle drop event but google don't provide it as of now. I had tried lot of other ways like HTML5 DnD etc but as addon renders as an iframe, it is unable to access the doc html. `window.parent` don't help.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Did you try using HTML5 Web Storage?  If you can get whatever you want into HTML5 Web Storage, then you can retrieve it from the sidebar.  I'd use Session Storage rather than Local.  [HTML5 Webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)  You'll need to add a timer to the sidebar to poll for the existence of your data in Session Storage.  If this sounds like it might work for you, let me know.  Can you post your code that gets the image?

Comment: @SandyGood Nothing is getting image as of now, that my problem :( I want to trigger an event whenever image gets dropped onto the document. Google don't provide any drop event. Do we have some other way to do so?

Comment: Don't know.  I haven't used the drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run into the same issues using the drag and drop API. It might have to do with making sure you set `<base target="_top">`. The script below was written in a google doc. Just drag an image from google images and it will display in the dialog box.

code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("Get Image");
  menu.addItem("Open Dialog", "openDialog").addToUi();
}

function openDialog(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "drag n drop")
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
 <style>
 span {
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Drag Image Here<br>
    <span><img id="img" heigth=></span>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).on('dragover', function(e) {e.preventDefault();return false;});
$(document).on('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(url){
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = url;
        if(parser.hostname === "www.google.com"){
          var src = parser.search.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
             $("#img").attr("src",src);
        }else{
          alert("please select an image from google images")
        }

    });
});
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it work if I drop image on google doc (not on my add-on sidebar)?

Comment: No there is no event fired when there is a drop event on the doc itself. Only on a window you control.

Comment: Yes, thats what currently I am doing, however, I was trying if I can do it from doc itself. BTW, thanks for your help :)